Unable to Connect to Docker Network on Windows
I am using docker-engine under windows and trying to run a simple client/server. They run ok without docker. But when using docker I sart the server which starts to listen (using -p 8080:8080), but when I run the client, I get:

"No connection could be made because the target machine actively
refused it"

I have tried with a network I have created and without,
any ideas what is the problem?

If you are using docker-desktop for Windows, you should be able to connect to your container by: host.docker.internal:<pg-port>

Here is a simple example using a postgres-container:
$ docker run -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pw -p 5432:5432 postgres
$ pg_isready -h host.docker.internal

-> host.docker.internal:5432 - accepting connections
